# How to fix Type matching error

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function to calculate radius, and the first input is centre of a circle and second is a point from the edge of the circle.

```
type Coord = (Int,Int)
getRadius :: Coord -> Coord -> Float
getRadius (x0,y0) (x1,y1) = sqrt(sqrX+sqrY)
                             where sqrX = (x1-x0)*(x1-x0)
                                   sqrY = (y1-y0)*(y1-y0)
```

This is my code but when I compile it , an error shows that "Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’. "
I think the output should be a float not int . How can I fix this error? thanks

Comment: Frequently if one only needs to *compare* distances, one does not calculate the distance, but the square distance, so in such case, you could drop the `sqrt`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [sqrt](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sqrt) accepts Floating number, but [fromIntegral](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fromIntegral) will help to explicitly type cast the integers to floating numbers:

```
getRadius :: Coord -> Coord -> Float
getRadius (x0,y0) (x1,y1) = sqrt(fromIntegral (sqrX+sqrY))
                             where sqrX = (x1-x0)*(x1-x0)
                                   sqrY = (y1-y0)*(y1-y0)
```

Comment: thanks for your helping,  how can I round the final answer to int type?

Comment: For example, by using http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round function